# Manga/manhua/manhwa about a demon king that trains heroes to survive so he can get more experience for killing them

Tags: story-identification, manga

Not exactly sure whether it was a manga, manhua, or manhwa, but I remember it being colored, maybe, I could be wrong.

I remember it being a story about a demon king, or lord, or emperor, any of those, who the line of demon kings are always destined to lose to the hero, and he does not want to die. So he goes and finds heroes or adventurers to train them high enough level so he could kill them to get experience and level up. Though he doesn't end up actually killing them from the point I remember leaving off at, and he may never will.

Though he thinks he's weak and will automatically lose to the hero, he is incredibly strong. I vividly remember the start of it being him panicking about that and decides to do this hero training plan, and he ends up saving a couple of people who he is deciding to train, the monster he kills barely gives him any exp. Somehow at some point I remember them being in a desert, but at this point it might just be my mind making stuff up.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters or locations?

Comment: Does it involve a clumsy elf archer and a male barbarian as per [this guy's question](https://www.reddit.com/r/manga/comments/gjdode/i_need_help_finding_a_manga_in_which_the_demon/) (no answer there, but maybe more information)?

Comment: Perhaps [*The Hero Life of a Self-Proclaimed Mediocre Demon*](https://myanimelist.net/store/manga/803/The_Hero_Life_of_a_Self-Proclaimed_Mediocre_Demon). It has the Demon King training heroes as best I can tell.

Comment: https://www.novelupdates.com/series/a-hero-trained-by-the-most-evil-demon-king-is-unrivaled-in-the-academy-of-returnees-from-another-world/ seems more a partial match.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, I can not recall exactly when besides it being a few years ago, or where, and no I do not remember names either, sorry for being unable to give more information. It is not that story, as for the other person's question, he did have a chief of staff sort of character that may be his sidekick.
I also do think there was a clumsy girl as well, can not confirm from memory whether she was an elf or not. As for the berserker, I can't confirm.

Comment: I actually found it after hours of searching through different aggregator sites, https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/ni-xi-ba-mo-wang
Maybe you can try helping that person from reddit if he has not found it still after 2 years, if he cares.

Comment: Hi Dave, please post this as an answer to the question; the answer will be searchable and much more visible that way.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is [Ni Xi Ba Mo Wong](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/ni-xi-ba-mo-wang), also known as Demon King's Counterattack.

[image: Title image]

> Leaving behind his throne, his wealth, and his women. The Demon King now disguises himself and start raising heroes in his pen?! He even formed a party to level up "newbies"! Aren't this suppose to be the war between Good and Evil?! Caesar mockingly answers: "Rules? I create the rules!"

Comment: You will be able to accept your self-answer tomorrow. Congrats!